# AWS/PHP Mysql Api - too many connections

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are hosting an admin system on our AWS EC2 T2.micro instance.

The admin is written in Angular and calls a PHP file to retrieve information.

We are currently running into a "Too Many Connections" error. I'm not sure if we've structured this correctly. I was hoping I could explain what we're doing and see if you guys have any suggestions on how to improve / eliminate this problem.

The way it works is our admin sends data up to a PHP file. The PHP file creates a connection to the database, retrieves the relevant information based on what data was passed up, echos it in JSON format that the admin reads it.

I looked up our max connections and it's set to 151. The app makes many calls to the 'API' PHP file per user. Example it makes one call to download the user, another to update their location, another to download all of the posts, another to download their pictures, etc.

I just added code at the end of the PHP file to close the connection after the data was retrieved and echoed. I'm not sure if this is the final solution though?

1.) How high can I set my max connections to / is there a number that's too high?
2.) Is there a way that each user only gets one connection as opposed to opening a new connection every time an API call is executed having our API on PHP?
3.) Should we ditch this structure altogether and what would be a better solution for this?
4.) Please drop any wisdom / knowledge you have on this topic! We're currently live and our customers are losing service over this :(

We first request information from Angular Admin site:

```
 $http.post($rootScope.api_url, data, { headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' } } )
        .success(
          function(response){
            deferred.resolve(response);
          }
        )
        .error(function(data){
              deferred.reject();
        });
```

Connection code on PHP 'API' file:

```
$this->admin_con = new mysqli($config['admin_dbhost'], $config['admin_dbuser'], $config['admin_dbpassword'], $config['admin_dbname']);
```

After it puts together all the information needed via a mysql statement we echo it out like so:

```
echo json_encode($this->returnArray);
```

After echoing the result:

```
mysqli_close($this->admin_con);
```

Comment: First, post some actual code; it's impossible to tell from your question whether this is a programming issue or a server admin issue. Second, caching is your friend. Third, you probably have additional problems, like inefficient code or inadequate database indexing, but you haven't posted enough information to help you with that.

Comment: Make sure you're not using persistent connections. Optimize your queries to make sure they aren't running too long. Use tools such as Persona Toolkit to optimize your database.

Comment: @EdCottrell Thanks for the feedback, I edited the OP and added code relevant to the question. Our PHP file is 2400 lines so I didn't want to post the whole thing. Let me know if that's enough information?

Comment: @aynber Thanks for the reply. We are not using persistent connections. Even if our queries were perfectly efficient, wouldn't this still be a problem if say each user logs into the app (opening say 20 connections for 20 different API calls per user). We would max out at 7 users logging in at any given time with a max connections set to 151.

I will look into Persona Toolkit.

Comment: Sorry, silly autocorrect. It's supposed to be Percona Toolkit.

Comment: @hunijkah If each user is making that many API calls on every page, that's a really good reason to implement some basic caching. Most of the data, like a user's personal information, posts, and pictures, will change only rarely, certainly not on every request. Most of that stuff belongs in a cache of some sort, probably something like Redis.